# Make SQL column names dynamic to change with month to month date changes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I am trying to improve a legacy code that is calculating monthly collections. Currently I delete the oldest month and create a new month to reflect the most recent month (e.g. cut june 2022 and make the new column june 2023). The current relevant segment of code looks like this:

```sql
SUM(CASE WHEN dd.YearMonth = '2022-08' THEN [Collections]   ELSE 0 END) AS Aug22_Collections,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dd.YearMonth = '2022-09' THEN [Collections]   ELSE 0 END) AS Sep22_Collections,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dd.YearMonth = '2022-10' THEN [Collections]   ELSE 0 END) AS Oct22_Collections,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dd.YearMonth = '2022-11' THEN [Collections]   ELSE 0 END) AS Nov22_Collections,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dd.YearMonth = '2022-12' THEN [Collections]   ELSE 0 END) AS Dec22_Collections,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dd.YearMonth = '2023-01' THEN [Collections]   ELSE 0 END) AS Jan23_Collections,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dd.YearMonth = '2023-02' THEN [Collections]   ELSE 0 END) AS Feb23_Collections,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dd.YearMonth = '2023-03' THEN [Collections]   ELSE 0 END) AS Mar23_Collections,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dd.YearMonth = '2023-04' THEN [Collections]   ELSE 0 END) AS Apr23_Collections,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dd.YearMonth = '2023-05' THEN [Collections]   ELSE 0 END) AS May23_Collections,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dd.YearMonth = '2023-06' THEN [Collections]   ELSE 0 END) AS Jun23_Collections,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dd.YearMonth = '2023-07' THEN [Collections]   ELSE 0 END) AS Jul23_Collections,
```

This sets up columns for my temp table with each column corresponding to a new month.

My new goal is for the column names to change names dynamically so that I no longer need to cut and paste and re-label this section. I know I'll need to change the "dd.YearMonth = '2023-07'" section and the "AS Jul23_Collections" part, but I'm unsure how to do so.

I assume that I could set variables like:

`DECLARE @Month1 INT = YEAR(DATEADD(MM,-1,GETDATE())) * 100 + MONTH(DATEADD(MM,-1,GETDATE()))`

and

`DECLARE @Month2 INT = YEAR(DATEADD(MM,-2,GETDATE())) * 100 + MONTH(DATEADD(MM,-2,GETDATE()))`

But I don't know if that can be used for the actual column name itself. That's my biggest struggle. Ideally I want each column name to be the correct corresponding month and then "_Collectons".

I tried to set start and end date variables, but this didn't change column names, which is my bigger problem currently.

Comment: Column names must be literals. This is a task for your presentation layer, not the SQL layer. For example using a matrix in SSRS/PowerBI or a Pivot Table in Excel.

Comment: you can always use dynamic sql to build a query like you have currently presented. in the worst case, it's just a bunch of set @sql +=  'sum case when ...'.